# How to force NuGet updates on other machines?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I installed a new NuGet package on my machine to get a library installed. This means I have other versions of the .NET compiler and so on. When I then push the project to my branch and others checkout and pull it, I assume their NuGet packages are different versions than mine. How do I get those to update on their machines, without doing `Install NUGET_PACKAGE` again, overriding everything I've done (like removing unnecessary folders)? Example:

Before:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
```

After:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.2\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.2\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
```

1.0.0 to 1.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is handled by NuGet restore.

The other developers do not need to reinstall the NuGet packages into the project. All the other developers need to do is restore the packages for the projects you have modified after they have checked it out.

If they are using Visual Studio 2015 the restore will generally be done when you build the project. There is also a Restore NuGet Packages menu if you right click the solution in the Solution Explorer if you want to manually trigger the restore.